# Center div over another div

Tags: html, css

First of all, I know there are a lot of questions with this title and I went through them.

Here is my case and what I tried. I have some divs with dinamically added content. What I want is to place the status on the middle of the dotted border. My problem is that if the content of let's say first div has two lines, then my status won't be on the middle of the dotted line.

How cand I make the status always stay in the middle of the dotted line regardless of other content?

EDIT: This is the mobile view of the component, on the desktop view the status should stay on the bottom right side of the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative
}

.border {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 0px;
}

.status {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
}
.status-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">some text </div>
  <div class="text">some other text</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="text">more text</div>
  <div class="status-wrapper">
    <div class="status">my status</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put the status inside the border element? Like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative
}

.border {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 0px;
}

.status {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
}
.status-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">some text </div>
  <div class="text">some other text</div>
  <div class="border">
    <div class="status-wrapper">
      <div class="status">my status</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">more text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a runnable "snippet," so your answer's code can be demonstrated inside of your answer. Please could you update that Snippet to show, and apply, the relevant CSS?

Comment: That should work, but i would create a container for the text below, with position relative, and put the status-wrapper with position absolute at the top-center

Comment: The CSS stays the same as shown in the question.

Comment: Sadly, I can't. This is the view on mobile. On desktop the status is displayed on bottom right side of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `border` and `status` in a container and set it to relative.

```css
.container {
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: relative
    }

    .border-container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .border {
      border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-left: 0px;
    }

    .status {
      z-index: 2;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0px 10px;
      width: -moz-fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
      background-color: pink;
      position: absolute;
      top: 60%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
    }
    .status-wrapper {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .text {
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">   
    <div class="text">some text </div>
    <div class="text">some other text</div>
    <div class="text">some more other text</div>
    <div class="text">some more more other text</div>
    <div class="border-container">
      <div class="status-wrapper">
        <div class="status">my status</div>
      </div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">more text</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `display: grid` and position the `.status-wrapper` (along with its child) in the same `grid-row` as the `.border` element:

```css
/* using CSS custom properties to allow for easier
   theming and future maintenance: */
:root {
  --color-accent: hsl(0 100% 50% / 1);
  --color-accent-90: hsl(0 100% 90% / 50);
  --color-primary: hsl(0 0% 0% / 1);
  --status-block-size: 32px;
  --white: hsl(0 100% 100% / 0.9);
}

.container {
  /* using the CSS keyword 'currentColor' to assign the
     value of the current color property (assigned or
     inherited) as the border-color: */
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  /* assigning a custom-property as the color property-
     value, using the var() function: */
  color: var(--color-primary);
  /* using CSS grid for layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* specifying one column taking all available space: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* using CSS logical properties in place of 'width' */
  inline-size: 500px;
}

.border {
  /* again, a CSS logical property; in this instance the
     block-dimension (size along the block-axis) is set
     to 100%; in the English language the inline-axis is
     left-to-right, and the block-axis is top-to-bottom: */
  block-size: 100%;
  /* using repeating-linear-gradient() to create the dashed
     "border" effect: */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, currentColor 0 5px, transparent 5px 10px);
  /* positioning that imgage at 0 on the inline-axis and 50%
     on the block-axis: */
  background-position: 0 50%;
  /* preventing repeats: */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* sizing the image to take 100% of the inline-axis
     and 1px on the block-axis (for a 1px 'thick'
     'border': */
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  /* in English, equivalent to 'width': */
  inline-size: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.status-wrapper {
  /* reducing the inline-size of the element to the size
     required to show the content of the element: */
  inline-size: fit-content;
  /* centering the element on the inline-axis: */
  justify-self: center;
}
.status {
  /* again, CSS custom properties for easy theming: */
  background-color: var(--color-accent-90);
  /* setting the border-radius according to the
     font-szie: */
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: var(--color-accent);
  justify-self: center;
  /* using an outline to create a visual separation
     between the 'status' and the 'border': */
  outline: 0.3em solid var(--white);
  padding-inline: 10px;
}

.border,
.status-wrapper {
  /* centering the elements on the cross-axis; the
     grid is set to columns (block-axis) but the
     content within is still flowing on the
     inline-axis; so align-self is - as 'cross-axis'
     might suggest - centering vertically (in Enlish
     language websites): */
  align-self: center;
  /* placing both the .border and .status-wrapper
     (and any descendants) in:
       grid-row: 3
       grid-column: 1
      using grid-area shorthand: */
  grid-area: 3 / 1;
  /* centering on the inline-axis within the grid-area: */
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">some text </div>
  <div class="text">some other text</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="text">more text</div>
  <div class="status-wrapper">
    <div class="status">my status</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p6nea4ms/).

I like the above solution for its relative simplicity, but dislike it because we're hard-coding the `grid-area` in which to position both the `.border` and `.status-wrapper`. I would much prefer to have the position of the `.status-wrapper` dynamically allocated to match the 'natural' position of the `.border` element.

Unfortunately, as yet, I've been unable to find a way to allow for that dynamic behaviour.

References:

- [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).
- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-).
- [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).
- [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).
- [CSS custom properties: `--*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`justify-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self).
- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`repeating-linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).